# How could I make a menu dropdown on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how could I make my menu drop down when i click on it instead of hover?
I want to be able to click on .logo and have the ul dropdown. and to also hide the menu when i click on it again. The div inside .logo is just a triangle pointing down.

html code:

```
<div id='Logo_dropdown'>
<ul>
   <li class='logo'><a href='#'><div></div></a></li>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#upload'><span>Upload Logo</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#Edit'><span>Edit Logo</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#Logo_dropdown ul {

  padding: 0;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;  
  position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -30px;
    font-size:14px;}
#Logo_dropdown li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;}

#Logo_dropdown a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#Logo_dropdown ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#Logo_dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#Logo_dropdown {
  height: 50px;
    position:absolute ;
    background: #FCFCFC;
  font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  left:200px;
  opacity:0.9;
filter:alpha(opacity=90); 
    padding-left:1%;
                padding-right:auto;
                width: 190px;

 /* background-color:#F3F3F3 ; /*color for Nav Menu Bar
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);*/
  width: 140px;
  z-index:1;
  }
#Logo_dropdown > ul > li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left:140px;}

#Logo_dropdown > ul > li > a {
  color: #999;
  font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  -webkit-transition: color .15s;
  -moz-transition: color .15s;
  -o-transition: color .15s;
  transition: color .15s;

}
#Logo_dropdown > ul > li > a:hover {
  color:#2bafb8; /*color nav menu bar when mouse hovers*/

}
#Logo_dropdown > ul > li > ul {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  left: 80%;
  margin-left: -90px;
  width: 250px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
  -o-transition: all .3s .1s;
  transition: all .3s .1s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width:100px;


}
#Logo_dropdown > ul > li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 95px; /*position of hover li*/

  z-index:1;
  overflow: visible;
}
#Logo_dropdown > ul > li > ul:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fafafa transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;

}
#Logo_dropdown > ul ul > li {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;

}
#Logo_dropdown ul ul a {
  color: #2bafb8;
  font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 5px 8px 7px 16px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  transition: background-color 0.1s;
}
#Logo_dropdown ul ul a:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}


#Logo_dropdown ul ul a:hover {
  background-color: #2bafb8;
  color: #f0f0f0 !important;
}   
div{
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-left: 20px solid transparent;
border-right: 20px solid transparent;
border-top: 20px solid #CCC;

}
```

Comment: Sharing for future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35869393/5898685

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use simply `toggle()` to view the dropdown :)

> I want to be able to click on .logo and have the ul dropdown

Use this :

```
$('.logo').click(function () {
  $('#logodropdown ul.second').toggle();
}
```

This way, it will show it if hidden, and hide it if visible. You can also set some speed if you want, inside the parathesis as `toggle(time in milliseconds)`.

And please change the second ul to `<ul class="second">` as the code might misunderstand your approach and hide both of the lists in the #logodropdown. This would be a good approach to what you want to happen! Or even use a class to differentiate between both the lists.

You can use CSS to do some stuff like `:active` or `:focus`. But they won't cause a change in the properties of other elements. That's where you need a help of jQuery. :)

Answer (score 0):

For click you will need to use Javascript, as there is no click event handling in CSS.

Comment: There is, however, the :active pseudo-class for when a link is depressed, but that goes away once the click is finished.

Comment: this is only a partial answer. you are right, but OP has gotten no further.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see the jQuery tag here and didn't think to add more.