# Removing autoload of dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

In my page i have set calendar as dropdown but it automatically loads in start up

my code is like this

```
<li class="dropdown"> 
<input type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" name="txtEnds" id="txtEnds" required >
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display:none;">
        <li><div id="showDates"></div></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

using showdates id i have created a calendar. All things are working properly but the problem is it is automatically loading in startup it makes a bad look to my site. I need to make that to only displaying it on clicking the textbox

Sorry for this simple question but i dont know what is the problem in it please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>If you set `data-toggle` property to `dropdown`, it will always display list contents on page load. I suggest you use `collapse` instead of `dropdown` and see the changes. Then you can work on it.</s>

Forget all. Here is a working calendar.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
        autoclose: true, 
        todayHighlight: true
  }).datepicker('update', new Date());;
});
```

```css
#datepicker{width:180px; margin: 0 20px 20px 20px;}
#datepicker > span:hover{cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

There you go... Works fine and made in bootstrap. There are literally hundreds of versions of this.

Comment: I have not much idea of bootstrap but i think the proble is in   this section     <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display:none;">
        <li><div id="showDates"></div></li>
    </ul>       after removing that textbox to it loads on the page. Please help me if you have any idea about it this is now a big issue for me

Comment: @RemyaR Change the class type to "collapse in" instead of "dropdown-menu." Sometimes Bootsrap is tricky. If that doesn't help, take a look at this example and let me know if you have any questions: (http://www.bootply.com/61710#)

Comment: but i need this as dropdown. My page has a lot of portions. Collapse makes a bad look. Sorry .

Comment: If you know the answer help me anyway i accepted your answer. And thanks for making time to help me

Comment: @RemyaR Please check above edit. Best I could do. Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks for your effort to help me

Comment: You're welcome. You can change the css & html codes to change how it looks. And don't forget to include external files (such as scripts and stylesheet I used) to your local project.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
});
```

> So, Then you can show on click datepicker.

Comment: Thanks for your response burt it doesnt worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code to

```
<li class="dropdown"> 
<input type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"   data-hover="dropdown" name="txtEnds" id="txtEnds" required onclick="showmydiv();">
<ul class="dropdown-menu" >
    <li><div id="showDates" style="display:none;"></div></li>
</ul>
</li>

<script>
    function showmydiv(){
       document.getElementById('showDates').style.display = "block";
      }
</script>
```

This one worked properly